# Pupeteer throwing error of File not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

I have the following code, for which I am converting an html page into PDF. I see the file is present in the location, but an error occurs when it run.

```
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

    var pdfPath = path.join("C:/Users/Testing");

    (async () => {
      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      var contentHtml = fs.readFileSync('file:///C:/Users/Mytesting/test.html', { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
      await page. setContent(contentHtml); 
      await page.pdf({path: pdfPath , format : 'A4'});
      await browser.close();
    })();
```

I can open the html file in browser and it renders properly.

#### Error:

> ```
> { Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'file:///C:/Users/Mytesting/test.html'
>     at Object.openSync (fs.js:443:3)
>     at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:343:35)
>     at C:\Users\shiva.nara\NodeProjects\KioskApp\controllers\node.controller.schedulesearch.js:768:28
>     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
>   errno: -4058,
>   syscall: 'open',
>   code: 'ENOENT',
>   path:
>    'file:///C:/Users/Mytesting/test.html' }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Your path pattern for an absolute path is wrong. You can omit `file:///`. Use instead the following:

```
fs.readFileSync('C:/Users/Mytesting/test.html');
```

Also don't use `{ waitUntil: "networkidle2" }`, as it is not a valid option. See [the fs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options).

Comment: I solved the problem. I need to pass the HTML code as the content, but not the whole page.